# How to add an email attachment from a byte array?

Tags: c#

I have a `byte[]` with the contents of file. I would like to send it as an attachment using `System.Net.Mail`.

I noticed the attachment class has 1 overload which accepts a stream.

```
Attachment att = new Attachment(Stream contentStream,string name);
```

Is it possible to pass the `byte[]` through this overload?

Comment: BTW, you can also use att.ContentDisposition if you want to set other attributes of the attached file (e.g. CreationDate).

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
Attachment att = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), name);
```

Note that unless you do funky stuff with asynchronous operations, `MemoryStream` is safe to leave undisposed, which may make life easier for you. Admittedly there's no *guarantee* that that will be true in the future, but I think it's unlikely that it will change. I can't see any indication as to whether disposing of the attachment disposes of its stream :(

Comment: Good point, I noticed when adding file based attachments, I needed to dispose the attachment object to release a handle on the file. Surely the stream should be taken care of by GC, because its not an IO operation?

Comment: FWIW, Mono's Attachment class calls `Dispose` on the content stream, and from a quick test case, .NET 4.0 does the same. I'm not super-amused that this is the case, but there it is.

Answer (score 40):

You need to convert the `byte[]` to a `MemoryStream` using the appropriate [MemoryStream constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx).

```
Attachment att = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(myBytes), name);
```

Note that the *name* parameter to [Attachment's constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sdktyws.aspx) specifies the name of the attachment's content type, not the name of the attachment itself.

Comment: It seems that name parameter is name of the file, not content type. See remarks: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime.contenttype.name.aspx