# Adding an attachment to email using C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, gmail, smtpclient

I'm using the following code from this answer [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail). The trouble I'm having is adding an attachment to the email. How would I add an attachment using the code below?

```
using System.Net.Mail;

var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "From Name");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("to@example.com", "To Name");
const string fromPassword = "fromPassword";
const string subject = "Subject";
const string body = "Body";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
};
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body
    })
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The `message` object created from your `new MailMessage` method call has a property `.Attachments`.

For example:

```
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(PathToAttachment));
```

Comment: This answers is incomplete. What if the attachments is not sitting in the file system, but you have a stream of byte?

Comment: @barduro The OP did not ask about that particular case. For that, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2583991/161052

Answer (score 19):

Using the Attachment class as proposed in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments.aspx):

```
// Create  the file attachment for this e-mail message.
Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
// Add time stamp information for the file.
ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file);
disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(file);
// Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.
message.Attachments.Add(data);
```

Comment: The "official documentation" on MSDN is pretty sketchy about what an Attachment actually attaches. Just like your example doesn't explain what "file" is or what will be attached if it works.

Answer (score 9):

Correct your code like this

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("your attachment file");
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-email-attachment.htm

hope this will help you.

ricky

Answer (score 1):

Hint: mail body is overwritten by attachment file path if attachment is added after, so attach first and add body later

```
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file));
mail.Body = "body";
```

Comment: I find no evidence to support this claim.

Answer (score 0):

A one line answer:

```
mail.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("pathToAttachment"));
```