C# how do I add a downloadable file email attachment without using local file system
I have files stored in the cloud (Azure Blob containers) that are downloadable and I want to attach them to an email that I am sending using c#, I don't want to use my local file system, can that be done?

is your question also about how to get blob? Because if your question is, how to add attachment, the "azure blob" part is extra and not needed. Your attachment is byte[], so is blob content, so is any file File.ReadAllBytes(path) Besides, what are you using to send email? SMTP, AWS SNS, Microsoft Graph/EWS?

I'm answering my own question here, a lot of what I found was writing the file to a local location and then attaching it.  Using Stream you can attach it straight away. I have horrible 'luck' on here, I don't know how to write up questions apparently.

In this case there is no value here in neither, the question, or the answer you've posted. The code you've posted is typical and has been reproduced in millions of copies. You've added azure tag but there is not even smell of azure in your code. Using Azure means creating Azure blob client and getting Blob, getting its content, which is file content stored in azure. You have a generic HttpClient code, which is more than common

i disagree, it took a lot of searching to find my solution, so I thought I'd share it...  doesn't matter whatever, just vote me down so more, would ya?

How do you know if I voted you down? And then, when you flag to moderators for closing some questions as "not an answer", they tell us to vote down, which forces OP to remove their input. Saying, this is natural way to self regulating community. In this case, your tag azure and your question title as well do not correspond to the desired output. You could title your question as "how to add attachment and send email in c#" And there - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034503/adding-an-attachment-to-email-using-c-sharp - I have your code

@T.S. is it worded better now?  ty

To get blob from Azure (where you store your files) connect to blob containers, get blob and create attachment. Using Azure nuget packages
using Azure;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

// create Azure blob client
var client = new BlobClient(connString, containerName, blobName);
// get download blob response. Also avail is overload with download options where you can specify how you want to download it  
Response<BlobDownloadResult> response = client.DownloadContent();

// get content as stream  
var stream = response.Value.Content.ToStream();
// Create mail attachment from stream
var a = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(stream, "filename");
// add attachment to the message - this is trivial
message.Attachments.Add(a);


Conclusion: since System.Net.Mail.Attachment can be created using stream, the source of stream does not matter. It does not have to come from the local hard drive. It can come from Web API call or other such server, like Web Service, etc. or even remote call, Redis DB and so on.

Use Stream: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            string url = "https://urlThatWillDownloadTheFile.com";
            Stream stream = null;
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
            msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, {file name}, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet));

Full email example:
            string to = "{to email address}";
            string from = "{from email address}";
            string subject = "{Subject}";
            string body = "{Body}";
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
            msg.From = new MailAddress(from);
            msg.Subject = subject;
            msg.Body = body;


            string url = "https://urlThatWillDownloadTheFile.com";
            Stream stream = null;
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
            msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, {file name}, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet));


            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "{host}";  //example: smtp.office365.com
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("{username}", "{password}");
            smtp.Send(msg);

