# Read data from SQL saved in varbinary format and attach file in email sent from system?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-web-api

I have tried to get the files from SQL using HttpResponseMessage and I wish to attach the file as an email sent by system.

```
 [Route("GetspecificDocument")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetspecificDocument(string searchText)
        {
            try
            {
                //DocumentMaster objFileReaderView = iEnquiryRepository.GetDocument(searchText);
                long docid = Convert.ToInt64(searchText);
                DocumentMaster objFileReaderView = coreContext.DocumentMasters.Where(t => t.DocumentId == docid).FirstOrDefault();
                HttpResponseMessage ResponseDownload = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                                
                ResponseDownload.Content = new ByteArrayContent(objFileReaderView.DocumentBinData);

                if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("pdf"))
                {
                    ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
                }
                else if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("png"))
                {
                    ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
                }
                else if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("jpg") || objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("jpeg"))
                {
                    ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
                }
                else if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("csv"))
                {
                    ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/csv");
                }
                else if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("doc"))
                {
                    ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/msword");
                }
                else if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("docx"))
                {
                    ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
                }
                else if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("xlsx"))
                {
                    ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                }
                else if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("xls"))
                {
                    ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                }
                else if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("zip"))
                {
                    ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
                }
                //ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = objFileReaderView.DocumentName;
                String reader = ResponseDownload.Content.ToString();
                return ResponseDownload;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }


//Code for email
 public async static Task<bool> SendMail(string toAddress, string[] ccName, string subject, string body)
        {
            try
            {
                string fromAddress = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmailAddr"];

                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);

                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress));
                foreach (string ccN in ccName) {
                    msg.CC.Add(new MailAddress(ccN));
                }                
                msg.Subject = subject;
                msg.Body = body;
               
                //msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(msg);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really needs 2 methods? you can have one action method that gets the document from database and send email..

```
public Task SendEmail(RequestObject request)
{
    // get document

   // send email
}
```

where RequestObject holds all the parameters that you need to query document and send email.

**Update 1**

Not sure if this what you are looking for

```
[Route("GetspecificDocument")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public HttpResponseMessage GetspecificDocument(string searchText)
{
    try
    {
        //DocumentMaster objFileReaderView = iEnquiryRepository.GetDocument(searchText);
        
        HttpResponseMessage ResponseDownload = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        ResponseDownload.Content = GetDocument(searchText);

        if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("pdf"))
        {
            ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        }
        else if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("png"))
        {
            ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
        }
        else if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("jpg") || objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("jpeg"))
        {
            ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
        }
        else if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("csv"))
        {
            ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/csv");
        }
        else if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("doc"))
        {
            ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/msword");
        }
        else if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("docx"))
        {
            ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        }
        else if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("xlsx"))
        {
            ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        }
        else if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("xls"))
        {
            ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        }
        else if (objFileReaderView.Type.ToLower().Contains("zip"))
        {
            ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
        }
        //ResponseDownload.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = objFileReaderView.DocumentName;
        String reader = ResponseDownload.Content.ToString();
        return ResponseDownload;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}


//Code for email
public async static Task<bool> SendMail(string toAddress, string[] ccName, string subject, string body, string searchText)
{
    try
    {
        
        string fromAddress = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmailAddr"];

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);

        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress));
        foreach (string ccN in ccName)
        {
            msg.CC.Add(new MailAddress(ccN));
        }
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.Body = body;

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
        {
            var doc = GetDocument(searchText);

            var attachment = BuildAttachmentFromBlob(doc);
            
            msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        }


        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(msg);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return false;
    }
}


private ByteArrayContent GetDocument(string searchText)
{
    long docid = Convert.ToInt64(searchText);
    DocumentMaster objFileReaderView = coreContext.DocumentMasters.Where(t => t.DocumentId == docid).FirstOrDefault();

    new ByteArrayContent(objFileReaderView.DocumentBinData)
}
```

Comment: multiple functions uses this feature hence I have separated the methods.

Comment: one option is to abstract how you get document from dbcontext. And then add `searchText` to sendEmail method. I will try to update my answer.

Comment: or better you can also abstract GetDocument and SendEmail into private methods. and then Create new action method something like `SendEmailWithAttachment`

Comment: I tried the same, but I wish to pass that bytarray as a file attachment in email sent using Mal message. Let me Know if you have any logic for the Same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583982/how-to-add-an-email-attachment-from-a-byte-array

Comment: Hello @LP13, 

Thank you for your response, but I am not able to us BuildAttachmentFromBlob can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: What's the SQL type of DocumentBinData coulmn?

Comment: DocumentBinData: Varbinary(max)